# codeigniter: how to show second row from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a site . now i like to show second row from db .
here is my model

```
public function select_main_body() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_main_body');
        $result_query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $result_query->row();
        return $result;
```

and i am display fast row with this

```
<?php echo $main_body_details->main_body; ?>
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you wanna fetch by ID, you should use $this->db->get_where();

Comment: hello naveed i like to show my second row from tbl_main_body which show me second row result.

Comment: Are you getting any correct output from this line: $result = $result_query->row(); I think you have to first get the result like in viyay's answer. Like $result = $result_query->result(); After that select the second row by using $result[1] or using the 1st index after returning the result

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
 public function select_main_body() {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('tbl_main_body');
            $result_query = $this->db->get();

            return $result_query ;
```

}

```
You call retrive this data 


foreach($result_query->result() as $row)
{
  print_r ($row);// you can retrive each record 

}
```

Comment: this is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the rownum in row()

Like

```
public function select_main_body() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_main_body');
    $result_query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $result_query->row(2);
    return $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function select_main_body() {
        $this->db->limit(1,1);
        return $this->db->get('tbl_main_body')->row();
}
```

This will give you 2nd row from database, if I was clear about your question.
OR

```
public function select_main_body() {
        return $this->db->get('tbl_main_body')->row(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
`$result_query->row()` into `foreach` and extract whatever row values you want to get.
```

like this:

```
foreach($result_query->result() as $row)
{
     echo $row['<name of the element you want to get>']
}
```

**UPDATE:**

see here, how I fetch different fields of the table, you will get the idea. I just used `while` in place of `foreach`

```
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {   
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            return;
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userpost WHERE userid = '".$user_id."' order by time DESC");
        while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $url = $row['url'];
            $preview = $row['preview'];
            $image = $row['img_url'];
            echo '<a class = "fragment" href = "'.$url.'" target = "_blank" >';
            echo '<div style="text-align: left;">';
            echo '<img src = "'.$image.'" height = "116" width = "116" alt = "some description"/>';
            echo '<span style="color:#7C7E7A;">'.$title.'</span>';echo '</br>';
            echo '<span style="">'.$url.'</span>'; echo '</br>';
            echo '<p class = "text" style="color:#85C5EB;" >'.$preview.'</p>';
            echo '</br>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</a>';
        }
```

Comment: hello Karim i m new in codeigniter. so i am confused. 
can you tell me how i use your code into my code ?

Thanks

Comment: i have tried this but not work
 `public function select_main_body() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_main_body');
        $result_query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $result_query->row();
        return $result;
        foreach ($result_query->result() as $row) {
            echo $row['2']; // you can retrive each record 
        }
    }`